# Routing without Action Name in Url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, action

I'm having problems with routing. I have News controller and I can read the details of a news from url `http://localhost/News/Details/1/news-title(slug)`. Here is no problem for now. But I created a controller called Services with Index action. Route config:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Services",
    "Services/{id}",
    new { controller = "Services", action = "Index" }
);
```

When my Index Action is

```
public ActionResult Index(string title)
{
    return View(title);
}
```

I write `localhost:5454/Services/sometext` by hand in browser it works.

But when change my index action to

```
public ActionResult Index(string title)
{
    Service service = _myService.Find(title);
    ServiceViewModel = Mapper.Map<Service , ServiceViewModel >(service );
    if (service == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(serviceViewModel);
}
```

I get Http Error 404 Not Found for Url localhost/Services/ITServices.

I can add this services from admin page with it's title (ITServices for example).
Then I do foreach in my Home Page for the services links

```
@foreach (var service Model.Services)
{
    <div class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block">
     @Html.ActionLink(service.Title, "Index", new { controller = "Services", id = service.Title }) 
    </div>
}
```

But I can't show the page in `localhost/Services/ITServices`.

When I click on the link I want to go to page localhost/Services/ITServices and it has to show the content(which can be added from admin page) like in the news. But I don't want to use it with action name and ids like in the news. How can I achieve this?

EDIT

Ok. I add `FindByTitle(string title)` in repository. I changed the `id` to `title` in RouteConfig and in the link in Home Page View. Then in my domain model deleted  Id and updated Title as [Key]. Now it works. Only have to check with remote validation for possible duplicates of Title when adding new from admin page.

Answer (score 3):

The parameter name in the URL template does not match the argument on the Action (`Index`).

So you can do one of two things.

Change the template parameter to match the argument of the Action

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Services",
   url: "Services/{title}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Services", action = "Index" }
);
```

Where Action Index is

```
public ActionResult Index(string title) { ... }
```

or you change the argument of the Action Index to match the paramater in the url template

```
public ActionResult Index(string id) { ... }
```

Where the route mapping is

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Services",
   url: "Services/{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Services", action = "Index" }
);
```

But either way the route is not finding route because it cannot match the parameters.

In fact if the intention is to use the title as a slug you could go so far as to use a catch all route for services like

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Services",
   url: "Services/{*title}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Services", action = "Index" }
);
```

Take a look at the answers provided here

[how to route using slugs?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37629565/5233410)

[Dynamic routing action name in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39185584/5233410)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
```