# Web api - how to route using slugs?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, routes

I would like to be able to parse links like this question is:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31223512/web-api-how-to-route-using-slugs
```

So route on the server simply *ignoring* the last part of the URL. As an example using this very question, how could I implement the routing correctly if somebody enters such an URL, it redirects me to:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31223512
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Referencing: [Handling a Variable Number of Segments in a URL Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#Anchor_5)

> Sometimes you have to handle URL requests that contain a variable
>   number of URL segments. When you define a route, you can specify that
>   if a URL has more segments than there are in the pattern, the extra
>   segments are considered to be part of the last segment. To handle
>   additional segments in this manner you mark the last parameter with an
>   asterisk (*). This is referred to as a catch-all parameter. A route
>   with a catch-all parameter will also match URLs that do not contain
>   any values for the last parameter.

A convention-based route could be mapped as...

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "QuestionsRoute",
    routeTemplate: "questions/{id}/{*slug}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Questions", action = "GetQuestion", slug = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

or, with attribute routing a route could look like...

```
[Route("questions/{id:int}/{*slug?}")]
```

which could both match an example controller action...

```
public IActionResult GetQuestion(int id, string slug = null) {...}
```

the example URL...

```
"questions/31223512/web-api-how-to-route-using-slugs"
```

would then have the parameters matched as follows...

- `id = 31223512`
- `slug = "web-api-how-to-route-using-slugs"`

And because the `slug` is optional, the above URL will still be matched to

```
"questions/31223512"
```

This should meet your requirements.