# Dynamic routing action name in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I would like to create a dynamic routing to a URL like following:

```
http://localhost:51577/Item/AnyActionName/Id
```

Please note that the controller name is static and doesn't need to be dynamic. On the other hand, I need to have the action name part dynamic so that whatever is written in that part of URL, I would redirect the user to the `Index` action inside of `Item` controller.

What I have tried so far is:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Items",
        "Item/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Item", action = "Index",  id = UrlParameter.Optional });
}
```

And when I build my app I get a following error:

> The resource cannot be found.

**Edit**:

Here is my `Global.asax` file and the `routeconfig.cs` file:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

And here's the content of the `RouteConfig.cs` file with the answer that @Nkosi provided:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Items",
            url: "Item/{id}/{*slug}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Item", action = "Index", slug = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: so even though someone request `item/create`, it should go to Index action ?

Comment: Yeah but it's never gonna be item/create, it's gonna be a item's name :)

Comment: So are you saying {action} part of the url is the name of the item ? Do you have a parameter ? can you share the Index action method signature and the url you are trying to access ?

Comment: Yes I can share, the ID of the item is the parameter that I'm going to use to retrieve the data on the item, and the dynamic action name is just to make it more human friendly :)

Comment: Can you share the url you are trying and how you expect that to map to ?

Comment: @User987, what you are trying to do is called a slug. take a look at this answer. only thing is that the slug is usually at the end of the url like `http://localhost:51577/Item/{Id}/{AnyActionName}` http://stackoverflow.com/a/37629565/5233410

Comment: Ah or it could be something like that... I'll have a look at it... Meanwhile could you write an answer so that I could accept it if it's correct :)

Comment: I did try as in that answer, but I'm still getting an error "Resource not found" :(...

Comment: @User987, are you mapping multiple routes. the order you map the routes is important as mapping follows a convention of first match wins. So check to make sure that specific routes are higher up and more generic routes are mapped later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are referring to in your question is called a slug.

I answered a similar question here for web api

[Web api - how to route using slugs?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37629565/5233410)

With the slug at the end the route config would look like this

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {

    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Items",
        url: "Item/{id}/{*slug}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Item", action = "Index", slug = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

}
```

which could match an example controller action...

```
public class ItemController : Controller {
    public ActionResult Index(int id, string slug = null) {
        //...
    }
}
```

the example URL...

```
"Item/31223512/Any-Item-Name"
```

would then have the parameters matched as follows...

- `id = 31223512`
- `slug = "Any-Item-Name"`

And because the slug is optional, the above URL will still be matched to

```
"Item/31223512"
```