# MVC Handling a Blog Request / Description URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have been asked to develop a blog system that has been completed, but my client would like to have the url in this format:

/Blog/{id}/A-Title/

I can create the URL in this fashion, but I cannot figure out how to call the controller "Blog" with these values; Mainly the "id".

I can get it to work with: /Blog/{id}?title=A-TItle, but this is not what they want.

Is this first version possible in MVC?

Regards

Comment: yes. its called a slug, look it up. if you look  at the url of this same stack overflow question you should realize that they are doing the same thing. the url template would look like `Blog/{id}/{*title}` where title is the slug. the `{*title}` parameter is known as a catch-all parameter and is usually at the end of a url template.

Comment: Take a look at the answer given here http://stackoverflow.com/a/39185584/5233410

Comment: That's it! Thank you ......

Comment: If everything works out you can vote up the answer if you found it useful.